# PhpStorm when I hit the tab button I see spaces

Tags: tabs, phpstorm

I just installed PhpStorm, looks great.

There is one thing that bothers me a lot -- when I hit the tab button I see a bunch of spaces.
When I hit shift+tab I can undo it, but when I tab and I hit the backspace I need to hit it a few times.

We work as a team and we decided to use tabs instead of spaces.

Is it possible that when I hit the Tab button that I actually see a tab and not a bunch of spaces?

I really hope that this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found it
if you are in a project: close the project: menu file -> close project
in the welcomescreen choose configure -> settings

in template project settings
menu codestyle choose use tab character
and choose all other programingstyles and check the "use tab character"
done